# Issue with Record Filter Strategy(Spring boot : 2.3.8). Filtered messages are coming again and again to the filter

Tags: spring-kafka

I am working on the spring kafka batch listener filter strategy. I am facing an issue that, the filtered events are coming again and again. could any one help me on this issue ? spring boot with kafka version(2.3.8)

Here is my configuration:

```
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new 
                  ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);

    factory.setBatchListener(true);
    factory.setAckDiscarded(true);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setIdleBetweenPolls(30000);
    factory.setRecordFilterStrategy(
            (consumerRecord) -> { 
                MyObject myObject = new ObjectMapper().readValue(consumerRecord.value(), MyObj.class);
                if (myObject.frequency > 10) {
                        return false;
                } else {  
                  return true;
                }});
   factory.setBatchErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler());
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean; if the listener fails to process the (filtered) batch (throws an exception), the whole batch will be resubmitted (and filtered again).

Comment: Thanks @Gary for your response. Basically, I am implementing the batch processing manually. I am trying to consume  the message when the MyObject frequency is greater than 10 or else discard the message. what i thought - discarding the message is during the poll, all the discarded messages offsets will be committed. is my understanding right ? Or do we need to explicitly commit the discarded message, so that it will not come again when manual batch mode?

Comment: Yes; the offsets for discarded records will be committed.

Comment: Yes.. that is not happening.  The discarded messages are coming again and again. Is there anything i need to check ?  The other application properties are spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode = MANUAL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using batch mode with MANUAL acks, if you filter all the records (discard them all), the listener will get an empty list so you can still acknowledge the batch to commit the offsets.

I just tested it and it works as expected.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So67259790Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So67259790Application.class, args);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so67259790", topics = "so67259790")
    public void listen(List<String> in, Acknowledgment ack) {
        System.out.println(in);
        ack.acknowledge();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so67259790").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> {
            template.send("so67259790", "foo");
            template.send("so67259790", "bar");
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public RecordFilterStrategy<Object, Object> rfs() {
        return rec -> true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Gary. What i thought was , the discarded messages never reach to lister. So i kept the listener acknowledge code in condition like below 
if (consumerRecords.size() > 0) { 
      acknowledgment.acknowledge();
}

Now i have removed and its working perfectly fine. Thank you so much for ontime help.